# List object not callable - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute a simple code on membership operators, and getting the following error.

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

```
    s="345"
print(list(s))
```

Comment: This works fine for me.

Comment: Please add your full error traceback and all relevant code to the question.

Comment: Works fine also for me

Comment: I think the error is in some other part of your code. It's working fine.

Comment: You probably have `mylist()` somewhere else in the code which causes the error as `mylist` is a list, not a function.

Comment: yeah am sorry the error is in some other line of the code. Am trying to convert string to list  x="66" print(list(x)) the error is in this line

Comment: You probably used `list` as a variable name somewhere.

Comment: No, I haven't used list keyword anywhere except here in the print statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me, too.
I also think you probably used a list as a variable name, too.

Can you tell us your python version or verbose inputs?

Otherwise, maybe it helps you to repair python.